# lm models for ANOVA III reveal wrong names as factors

Tags: r, factors

I am studying acidification effect on Growth rate (GR) and needed to implement an ANOVA III ways for this matter (with 3 factorial variables : pH (7.5,7.75, 8.1), Photoperiod (day or night) and phase (1 or 2)). While everything ran smoothly I have a hard time fixing factors name once displaying the results of my ANOVA III. For instance, R shows me "pH1" instead of "pH 7.75" as it is referred in the dataframe. I think it is linked with how I built my model with `contr_sum` in `contrasts` (which was needed for ANOVA III). I have already made sure that my variables were factors.

Here is an example of my code and the results as well as a piece of randomly generated dataframe:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(stats)
data <- data.frame(pH = rep(c(7.5, 7.75, 8.1), each = 10),
                 Photoperiod = rep(c("Day", "Night"), times = 15),
                 Phase = rep(c(1, 2), each = 15),
                 GR = runif(30, min = 0, max = 1))
data$pH <- as.factor(data$pH)
data$Photoperiod <- as.factor(data$Photoperiod)
data$Phase <- as.factor(data$Phase)
mod <- lm(GR ~ pH * Photoperiod * Phase, data=data, contrasts=list(pH=contr.sum, Photoperiod=contr.sum, Phase = contr.sum))

tab_model(mod)
```

Results :

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t78Z1.png)

Do you know anyway to change those factors' name ?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Note that R uses Type I rather than Type III although `aov3` in the sasLM package can be used to get Type III Anova in a similar way to SAS.

Regarding the `lm` variable names, using the input data shown in the question (also in the Note at the end) use `contr.Sum` from the car package.  The `S` in the resulting names refers to sum contrasts.  See `?contr.Sum` for details.

```
library(car)

contrasts(data$pH) <- contr.Sum(levels(data$pH))
contrasts(data$Photoperiod) <- contr.Sum(levels(data$Photoperiod))
contrasts(data$Phase) <- contr.Sum(levels(data$Phase))

mod <- lm(GR ~ pH * Photoperiod * Phase, data = data)

variable.names(mod)
## [1] "(Intercept)"                   "pH[S.7.5]"                    
## [3] "pH[S.7.75]"                    "Photoperiod[S.Day]"           
## [5] "Phase[S.1]"                    "pH[S.7.5]:Photoperiod[S.Day]" 
## [7] "pH[S.7.75]:Photoperiod[S.Day]" "Photoperiod[S.Day]:Phase[S.1]"
```

### Note

The input data as defined in the question:

```
data <- data.frame(pH = rep(c(7.5, 7.75, 8.1), each = 10),
                 Photoperiod = rep(c("Day", "Night"), times = 15),
                 Phase = rep(c(1, 2), each = 15),
                 GR = runif(30, min = 0, max = 1))
data$pH <- as.factor(data$pH)
data$Photoperiod <- as.factor(data$Photoperiod)
data$Phase <- as.factor(data$Phase)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly! I forgot to mention that after creating the model "mod" I applied function Anova(mod, type = 3). I believe it is the same idea as aov3 or am I mistaken ?

Comment: Anova type 3 and Type III in SAS and the sasLM package do not use the same notation of Type III.  See https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7327187/